# How to use array correctly

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to initialize an array and insert some values into it in Java, but I get out of bounds exception. This is the code

```
int xPoints[] = new int[]{};
int i = 0;
for(Edge e : myVectorOfEdges){
    xPoints[i] = e.start;
    i++;

}
```

I must use this type of data structure, because I am working with polygons which accept only `int[]` type.

Comment: Your initialization of xPoints is incorrect. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range

Comment: what type of `myVectorOfEdges` is it?

Comment: @Andrew it's Edge type, a class which created, it stores start and end point indexes in it

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized `xPoints` as an empty array, so any attempt to access one of its (non-existent) elements will result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Instead, you should initialize it to the same size as `myVectorOfEdges` which you are iterating:

```
int xPoints[] = new int[myVectorOfEdges.length];
```

Comment: The problem with this implementation is the length on the vector is much larger than I actually need to use, because it contains all edges from my input file, while I need to iterate through it and look for polygons, and than create xPoints[] for each polygon I find

Answer (score 1):

```
int xPoints[] = new int[myVectorOfEdges.length];
    int i = 0;
    for(Edge e : myVectorOfEdges){
        xPoints[i] = e.start;
        i++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the slow version:

```
    int[] xPoints = myVectorOfEdges.stream().mapToInt(e -> e.start).toArray();
```

Comment: are you sure that `myVectorOfEdges` is not an array?